# SQL query sum and max one table, join to get corresponding value of another

Tags: sql-server, database, dbvisualizer

I'm trying to query some data from SQL such that it sums some columns, gets the max of other columns and the corresponding value from another table. For example,

|table1|

```
 |id|   |shares|  |date|      
  1       100      05/13/16     
  2       200      05/15/16     
  3       300      06/12/16     
  4       400      02/22/16
```

|table2|

```
 |id|   |price|
  1       21.2
  2       20.2
  3       19.1
  4       21.3
```

I want my output to be:

```
 |shares|  |date|      |price|
  1000      06/12/16    19.1
```

The shares have been summed up, the date is max(date), and the price is the price at the corresponding max(date).

So far, I have:

```
select 
    id, stock, side, exchange, 
    max(startdate), max(enddate),
    sum(shares), sum(execution_price * shares) / sum(shares), 
    max(limitprice), max(price)
from 
    table1 t1
inner join
    table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
where 
    location = 'CHICAGO' 
    and startdate > '1/1/2016' 
    and order_type = 'limit'
group by 
    id, stock, side, exchange
```

However, this returns:

```
 |shares|  |date|      |price|
  1000      06/12/16    21.3
```

which isn't the corresponding price for the max(date).

Comment: could you please explain how your expected output came with Price as 19.3 when there is no such value in Table2  ???

Comment: Apologies. That should be 19.1. Edited

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE (id int, shares int, [date] date)
DECLARE @TableB TABLE (id int, price float)

INSERT @TableA 
VALUES
(1,100, '05/13/16'),
(2,200, '05/15/16'),
(3,300, '06/12/16'),
(4,400, '02/22/16')

INSERT INTO @TableB 
VALUES
(1, 21.2),
(2, 20.2),
(3, 19.1),
(4, 21.3)

SELECT
    t.*,
    tb.price
FROM
(
    SELECT
        SUM(ta.shares) as shares_sum,
        MAX(ta.date) as date_max
    FROM @TableA AS ta
) AS t
INNER JOIN @TableA AS ta ON t.date_max = ta.[date]
INNER JOIN @TableB AS tb ON tb.id = ta.id
```

Comment: @08351ty can you accept this answer, or I need to add something?

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.shares, a.date 
from (
select
(select sum(shares) from table1) as date,
max(a.date) as shares

from table1 a)
) t1
join table2 t2 on t1.date = t2.date
```